Using PWM with 9 volts
I am trying to power a DC motor for a minifan, and want to be able to control the speed of the motor through PWM.  In order for the motor to generate good wind, it needs 9 volts. Since I am using an Arduino Uno R3, I was wondering if there was an electrical device similar to a relay but that could sufficiently open and close a circuit quickly. Does anyone know how to solve this?

You can use a MOSFET which can easily switch fast enough. You just need to make sure that your Vgs is high enough to switch the FET cleanly.


I was wondering if there was an electrical device similar to a relay
but that could sufficiently open and close a circuit quickly.

Probably best served with a MOSFET and probably an N-channel MOSFET.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Depending on your skill level, who you ask and, your equipment, it could be a MOSFET and driver IC, an IC that has the motor drive function contained along with a MOSFET or, maybe you might be able to use a buck type regulator or, just a logic level MOSFET with no extra driver.
Motors are not usually driven from small 9 volt batteries (PP3) but, maybe your is a lantern type battery (PP9): -

Image from here
